# Zypper completely not working

Tags: linux, libraries, suse, zypper

I've experienced a sudden error when trying to run `zypper` by any form:

```
zypper: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libzypp.so.908: undefined symbol: gzdopen
```

Not very sure how to fix that, since the latest package of libzypp is asking me for tons of dependencies when i try to install it:

```
sudo rpm -i --force http://widehat.opensuse.org/opensuse/update/leap/15.0/oss/x86_64/libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64.rpm

error: Failed dependencies:
        libboost_thread.so.1.66.0()(64bit) is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.16)(64bit) is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        libproxy.so.1()(64bit) is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        librpm.so.8()(64bit) is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        libsolv-tools = 0.6.35 is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.18)(64bit) is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.19)(64bit) is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.22)(64bit) is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        libudev.so.1()(64bit) is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        libudev.so.1(LIBUDEV_183)(64bit) is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by libzypp-17.6.4-lp150.2.3.1.x86_64
```

Comment: By what I understand, I'm not even able to update `libzypp` like that, since it gives a weird dependence with `rpmlib`.... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the question. Apparently the entire /usr - related configuration of the system was broken, so I had to go for a backup.

Nothing worked as to solve the zypper crash - it seems that at some point when installing libraries/modules a non-compatible version was forced, which led to irreparable damage.